# Jquery foreach loop to set values

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span name="abc">ashgs</span>
<span name="abc">ashdf</span>
<span name="abc">asdxdx</span>
<span name="abc">mnnkfvdj</span>
<span name="abc">bsbdb</span>
```

I want to set a particular value in all these span's using jquery foreach loop
Please help as i am poor i jquery
Thanks in advance

Comment: The documentation provides a couple of examples: http://api.jquery.com/each/.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you replace all of your `.abc` classes'value, with another

```
$('.abc').each(function(){
    $(this).html('hello');
});
```

or the following way for a value, just as @Sudhir said

```
$("span[name='abc']")
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hb9LN/

Comment: in my case ` $(this).val(0);` works

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
$("span[name='abc']").each(function() {
   //set what you want, like rel
   $(this).attr("rel", "some_value");
});
```

See here; [jQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't understood what do you want to achieve, here is a effort which i understood with your question:

---

```
$('span[name="abc"]').each(function (i, v) {
  var valArr = ['Now!', 'This', 'is', 'placed', 'better'];
  $(this).text(valArr[i]);
});
```

find this in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hWExC/

---

Or a better one:

```js
$('span[name="abc"]').text(function () {
    var valArr = ['Now!', 'This', 'is', 'placed', 'better', 'wow!!!'];
    return valArr[$(this).index()];
});
```

```css
span{border:solid 1px red; padding:5px; margin:10px 0 0 0; display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span name="abc">ashgs</span>
<span name="abc">ashdf</span>
<span name="abc">asdxdx</span>
<span name="abc">mnnkfvdj</span>
<span name="abc">bsbdb</span>
```

Comment: Best answer here... addresses the true problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean set the html content of the span, then

```
$("span[name='abc']").html('the content');
```

Not necessary to use `.each()`.

Comment: that's the purpose of `.each()`, so using it, is the proper way to do it.

Comment: @w0rldart Why? It's already done inside `.html()`, why you need to do it again.

Comment: @w0rldart You could check the source code, you will find the loop is already done inside the `.html()` method.